# Validating record on insert and restricting insert if the date range of entry already exists

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My Table Structure is as Below

> select * from Table_name

```
Name     Start_Date      End_Date
XXY      14-FEB-2016     3-MAR-2016
XXD      21-JAN-2016     1-FEB-2016
XXY      18-FEB-2016     3-MAR-2016
XXD      21-JAN-2016     1-FEB-2016
XXD      22-JAN-2016     1-FEB-2016
```

The Data has issue where the same name has overlapping date range.

> For example, XXY

```
XXY      18-FEB-2016     3-MAR-2016
```

is not valid since the start_date is in between the date range of the existing record

```
XXY      14-FEB-2016     3-MAR-2016
```

The objective is to restrict insert of a record if it's start_date is in between any of the existing records under the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
DECLARE @from DATE = '2016-02-10'
DECLARE @to DATE = '2016-02-12'

INSERT INTO mytable (Name, Start_Date, End_Date)
SELECT Name, start_date, end_date
FROM (VALUES ('XXY', @from, @to)) AS t(Name, start_date, end_date)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS m
                  WHERE m.name = t.Name AND 
                  (t.start_date <= m.End_Date AND t.end_date >= m.Start_Date))
```

The values to be inserted are used in order to construct an in-line table with [**`VALUES`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) table value constructor. Using `NOT EXISTS` we can filter-out any overlapping rows and keep only the non-overlapping ones.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb535/1)

Comment: The Linked Demo is empty

Comment: @szakwani I just tried it and it works ok. sqlfiddle has some lag issues from time to time.